# What is a useful Azure IoT Hub JSON message structure for consumption in Time Series Insights

Tags: json, azure, time-series, azure-iot-hub

The title sounds quite comprehensive, but my baseline question is quite simple, I guess.

## Context

I Azure, I have an IoT hub, which I am sending messages to. I use a modified version one of the [samples from the Azure Iot SDK for python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/tree/master/azure-iot-device/samples).

Sending works fine. However, instead of a string, I send a JSON structure.

When I watch the events flowing into the IoT hub, using the Cloud shell, it looks like this:

```
PS /home/marcel> az iot hub monitor-events --hub-name weathertestiothub
This extension 'azure-cli-iot-ext' is deprecated and scheduled for removal. Please remove and add 'azure-iot' instead.
Starting event monitor, use ctrl-c to stop...
{
"event": {
        "origin": "raspberrypi-zero-wh",
        "payload": "{ \"timestamp\": \"1608643863720\", \"locationDescription\": \"Attic\", \"temperature\": \"21.941\", \"relhumidity\": \"71.602\" }"
    }
}
```

## Issue

The data seems fine, except the payload looks strange here. BUT, the payload is literally what I send from the device, using the SDK sample.

Is this the correct way to do it? At the end, I have a very hard time to actually get the data into the Time Series Insights model. So I guess, my structure is to be blamed.

## Question

**What is a recommended JSON data structure to send to the IoT hub for later use?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the tip by @elhorton, but it was not the key change. Nonetheless, the formatting in the Azure Shell Monitor looks now much better:

```
"event": {
    "origin": "raspberrypi-zero-wh",
    "payload": {
        "temperature": 21.543947753906245,
        "humidity": 69.22964477539062,
        "locationDescription": "Attic"
    }
}
```

The key was:

1. include the message source time in ISO format

```
    from datetime import datetime
    timestampIso = datetime.now().isoformat()
    message.custom_properties["iothub-creation-time-utc"] = timestampIso
```

2. Using the `locationDescription` as the `Time Series ID Property` See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/how-to-select-tsid (Maybe I could also have taken the `iothub-connection-device-id`, but I did not test that alone specifically)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following 2 lines to your message in your python SDK sample:

```
msg.content_encoding = "utf-8"
msg.content_type = "application/json"
```

This should resolve your formatting concern.

We've also updated our samples to reflect this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/sync-samples/send_message.py

Comment: Hi and welcome on Stackoverflow. This site works a little bit different than a typical forum and puts much more focus on giving direct answers to questions. I formatted your post a bit in this direction. It is also very welcomed to disclose so if you are working for an involved company, Microsoft in this case.

Comment: Adding the encoding and type is a good tip, although not the deciding one. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I guess using "`iothub-connection-device-id`" will make "`raspberrypi-zero-wh`" as the name of the time series instance. I agree with your choice of using "`locationDescription`" as TSID; so **Attic** becomes the time series instance name, **temperature** and **humidity** will be your variables.

Comment: Yes, at this time I think you are absolutely correct. The first time I used literally `deviceId`only, because I did not understand the significance of the exaxt value. Unfortunately, the raw messages are not visible in the Cloud Shell, the way I describe in my question. This can be a hindrance in understanding the mechanics in the background.